# Xamarin Evolve - Problems when building the solution

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using `MSVS2015 PRO`. I just downloaded `Xamarin Evolve` project and I'm having problems when compiling the solution as you can see on the image below.

I have problems with the `Gcm` and `WindowsAzure` namespaces as you can see on the file: `GcmService.cs`.

Notice there are also some `warnings` on the `solution explorer` on the right.

Any idea on how to fix all this small issues so I can build the solution successfully?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to restore the nuget packages.

Comment: I right clicked the solution and then clicked the option: "Restore NuGet Packages" but the problem persists. I also tried cleaning and rebuilding but no success.